# How to share database details in Github correctly, using Django and PostgreSQL?

Tags: django, postgresql, github

I have an assignment in which I need to set up a database server using Python Django and PostgreSQL. I need to assign the project in Github, and the grader will use my repository to check my project.

In my `setting.py` file I have the following lines:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'CourseDB',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

What to do so the details on my file will be correct for the grader's side?

Will they have to create a database with the given name, user and password like the ones in my file?

I think that maybe for the database name, I can add in the readme to run `CREATE DATABASE CourseDB` first. But then again, I don't know their user and password on their machine, So I don't know what should be written in my file in order for my code to work on their machine.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pwwz4_AvHDU&t=517s) tutorial on YouTube to create my file.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Docker?

Comment: no - only django and postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need some Postgres specific functionality, you can use the default SQLite backend:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Django will automatically create a database file. No setup/user/password needed.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you very much! however I must have the host on 'localhost' and port in 5432...

Comment: That is PostgreSQL specific. You don't need that for SQLite.

Comment: Lecturer insturcted to use PostgreSQL only, said nothing about SQLite, so I'm not sure this is allowed. What will be the host and the port, when using SQLite?

Comment: SQLite doesn't use hosts and ports. It's just a file inside the Django project.

Comment: If I'm running a React Server on another port in my computer, how can I make requests? When I have host, I can request (such as GET and POST) but I'm not sure how to do it with the file you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

In general, a good practice is to save all the DB sensitive credentials in `settings.py` using env vars like the following:

```
import os

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ['DATABASE_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DATABASE_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['DATABASE_HOST'],
        'PORT': os.environ['DATABASE_PORT'],
    }
}
```

Several DB backends are natively supported (see the official docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/)) including PostgreSQL, MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle and SQLite and a number of  additional backends provided by third parties.

If you go with the SQLite backend (for sure the best alternative for quick development and MVPs), keep in mind that there are some differences specific to the SQLite backend that you should take into consideration (e.g. not supported features).